# Parsing a JSON file using Javascript/JQUery

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have this JSON file:

```
{
"guest": {
    "permissions": {
        "webportal": [
            "access",
            "modify"
        ],
        {…}
        "test/dashboard": [
            "access"
        ]
    },
    "users": [
        "guest"
    ],
    "time_out": "3600000"
},
"administrator": {
    "permissions": {
        "webportal": [
            "monitoring",
            "access",
            "modify"
        ],
       {…}
        "test/settings": [
            "access",
            "modify"
        ]
    },
    "users": [
        "admin"
    ],
    "time_out": "3600000"
  }
}
```

What I need to do is simply take the FIRST items and drop them into a select box.  So for instance:

GUEST, ADMINISTRATOR and ANYTHING under the "users" section, could be 'n' number of entries, needs to be put into a select like this:

```
<select id='JSONFile'>
     <option value='administrator'>administrator</option>
     <option value='guest'>guest</option>
     <option value='useradmin'>useradmin</option>
</select>
```

The balance of the data in the JSON file needs to put into an array so that I can access it later and dump it into values for `CheckBoxes`.

For example: Under Guest: Permissions: `WebPortal - there's ACCESS and MODIFY`. That's the only two permissions there are.  So for the Guest to access the WebPortal; they must have ACCESS Permissions. To edit, MODIFY. get it?

So I'm new to this stuff and simply need to make it as simple as possible.

Oh yeah, did I mention we're using `KNOCKOUT` and the drop down has to be a KO Observable Array? But one thing at a time.

Part two comes later.

Ciao!

Comment: How do you get this JSON? Is it static or being retrieved via an AJAX call?

Comment: this is DYNAMIC... so, a user can add adInfinitum number of USERs but the Admin and Guest can NEVER be deleted. Only the properties of GUEST can be changed as well as the USER defined items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get and display the keys of the highest level objects in a select element, use the following code.

```
var optionValues = [];

var data = JSON.parse(JSONdata);       //this parses your data securely into an object that you can easily use
for(option in selection) {             //goes through the highest level keys of the object
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(option)) {   //this ignores the default object properties (things you don't want)
    if(option === 'users')             //takes into account user titles
      JSONdata['users'].forEach(function(userTitle) { //iterates over all of the user data and appends usertitles to the array
        optionValues.push('user'+userTitle);
      });
    else {                           // for the default roles like admin
      optionValues.push(option);     //this puts all of the non-user keys into an array 
    }
  }
}
```

This would output => `['guest','administrator','useradmin']` for the data you posted above.
You could then use document.createElement and document.appendChild to create options for all of these and place them under a select element in the document.

Answer (score 0):

My life with knockout got much easier after I understood the knockout mapping plugin.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html.

With that you can create the model automatically from the JSON data.

```
viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
```

Once in the viewModel you can iterate to your hearts content.  you may want to add a root node to your json data so it is easier to iterate over the roles.